# Running calculation in Power BI/DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's have two tables, an order book and a stock quantities.

Order book:

[image: Order book]

Stock quantities:

[image: Stock quantities]

How can I calculate the value of the parts in stock in sales prices considering their date?

The table I want to get is

[image]

5500 is clearly 2500 + 3000.

12500 is 10000 + 2500 = 100 units * 100 price + 50 units * 50 price

1550 is 500 + 1050 =  50 * 10 + (50 * 20 + 50 * 10) / (50 + 50) * 70

Comment: Can you clarify/explain in a bit more detail your calculation for C?

Comment: The 120 pieces of C parts in stock will be delivered in day 5 (50 pcs for 10 price) and in day 6. There is an average of the 20 and 10 price needed, since there are two deliveries in the day.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. After you take the 50 pcs at 10 price from Day 5, you require a further 70 pcs from Day 6. I don't see how your current calculation relates to those remaining 70 pcs.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I fixed the calculation. Anyway, what is the way to make the running balance in PBI?